# Exec problem in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the situation where i have two databases with same structure. The first have some data in its data tables. I need to create a script that will transfer the data from the first database to the second. I have created this script.

```
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(MAX),
        @query nvarchar(MAX)

DECLARE @table_cursor CURSOR 

SET @table_cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

    OPEN @table_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @table_cursor
    INTO @table_name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       SET @query = 'INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' SELECT * FROM MyDataBase.dbo.' + @table_name   
       print @query
       exec @query

       FETCH NEXT FROM @table_cursor
       INTO @table_name
    END

    CLOSE @table_cursor
    DEALLOCATE @table_cursor
```

The problem is that when I run the script the "print @query" statement prints statement like this

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM MyDataBase.dbo.table
```

When I copy this and run it from Management studio it works fine. But when the script tries to run it with exec I get this error

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'INSERT INTO table  SELECT * FROM MyDataBase'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Hope someone can tell me whot is wront with this.

Best Regards,

Iordan Tanev

Comment: For one, the error message only shows Database part or a tablename (I don't know what MPDEV090314 is supposed to be). Perhaps it would be better if you posted the actual print @Query statement instead of the *something like this*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue exactly...

You'd need to make it "dynamic SQL"

```
exec (@query)
```

`EXEC @Query` is actually `EXEC @module_name_var` with no brackets. See [EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) in MSDN. You want "Execute a character string" not "Execute a stored procedure or function"

However, I'd consider investing in something like [Red Gate Compare bundle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_bundles/SQL_Comparison_Bundle.htm) if it's something you need to do often

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use the undocumented but extremely helpful `sp_msForEachTable` stored procedure to achieve this - instead of using a cursor to execute dynamic SQL.

In that case, you'd have a statement something like this:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'INSERT INTO ? SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.?'
```

where the ? would get replaced with the actual table name for each table in the database. This requires that the tables already exist in your target database.

Check out some resources on `sp_msForEachTable` for more details:

- [SQL Server Undocumented Stored Procedures sp_MSforeachtable and sp_MSforeachdb](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)
- [8 Common Uses of the undocumented Stored Procedure sp_MSforeachtable](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/8-common-uses-of-undocumented-stored.html)
- [Using sp_msForeachTable](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/03/25/60596.aspx)
- [The undocumented sp_MSforeachtable procedure](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx)